# Breaking lines with "\<NL>" not working in GNUmake?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile *WORKING* fragment:

```
LOWER_PKG := skeleton-init-common toolchain-external-custom argp-standalone cpio dosfstools ncurses libzlib util-linux e2fsprogs iputils xz kmod lzo mtd busybox bzip2 dhcpcd d
LOWER_OVR := $(BR2_EXTERNAL_VOCORE2_PATH)/overlay
LOWER_ADD :=.

define ROOTFS_LOWER_REMOVE
        echo "ooo $(LOWER_OVR)"
        echo "ppp $(LOWER_PKG)"
        echo "aaa $(LOWER_ADD)"
endef
```

If I split the first long line using  normal "\newline" syntax it doesn't work anymore (all variables are printed empty, not just last one:

```
LOWER_PKG := skeleton-init-common toolchain-external-custom \
             argp-standalone cpio dosfstools ncurses libzlib \
             util-linux e2fsprogs iputils xz kmod lzo mtd busybox \
             bzip2 dhcpcd
LOWER_OVR := $(BR2_EXTERNAL_VOCORE2_PATH)/overlay
LOWER_ADD :=.

define ROOTFS_LOWER_REMOVE
        echo "ooo $(LOWER_OVR)"
        echo "ppp $(LOWER_PKG)"
        echo "aaa $(LOWER_ADD)"
endef
```

Note: I have TAB chars at start of line, but I don't know how to type them here, so I substituted 8 blanks.

What am I doing wrong?

That is absolutely the only change: I had a non working Makefile, joined the lines and it started doing its work just fine. I'm very baffled.

Note2: this fragment is a configuration part of a Buildroot compilation, which is a behemoth completely out of my control (if it matters).

Comment: In GNUmake 4.2.1 both versions work as intended. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whatever the problem is, it has nothing to do with what you've shown us in this question.  It must be somewhere else.  You can try adding debugging by introducing `$(info LOWER_PKG = $(LOWER_PKG))` etc. into your makefiles to figure out where and when, and hence hopefully why, your variables were emptied.

Comment: @Vroomfondel: 
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu